# TestKit for Akka Durable State

Tags: akka

I am using Akka Durable State feature for my project. Earlier I was using EventSourcedBehavior. Now I am using DurableStateBehavior. My code is working fine, but all my existing JUnits are failing.
I was using PersistenceTestKit. Is there any other test kit to be used for DurableState. I could not find any help regarding this topic.

Any working sample would be of great help.

I was expecting PersistenceTestKit to work for DurableState. Using expectPersisted should be able to give me persisted state data. I basically want to verify what is persisted.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

class InterimActorTest {
@ClassRule
public static final TestKitJunitResource testKit =
new TestKitJunitResource(
PersistenceTestKitPlugin.getInstance()
.config()
.withFallback(ConfigFactory.defaultApplication().resolve()));

```
PersistenceTestKit persistenceTestKit = PersistenceTestKit.create(testKit.system());






@BeforeAll
public static void init() {
    if (sharding == null) {
        Cluster cluster = Cluster.get(testKit.system());
        cluster.manager().tell(new Join(cluster.selfMember().address()));
        sharding = ClusterSharding.get(testKit.system());
        sharding.init(
                Entity.of(
                        InterimActor.TYPE_KEY,
                        entityContext ->
                                ProbedInterimActor.create(
                                        myClient,
                                        parentActorProbe,
                                        childActorProbe,
                                        entityContext.getShard(),
                                        cleanup)));
    }
}


@BeforeEach
public void setUp() throws JsonProcessingEx     g {
    persistenceTestKit.clearAll();
    parentActorProbe = testKit.createTestProbe(ParentActor.Command.class);
    childActorProbe = testKit.createTestProbe(ChildActor.Command.class);
}


@Test
void testStartToInterimActor() {
    EntityRef<InterimActor.Command> underTest =
            sharding.entityRefFor(InterimActor.TYPE_KEY, jobId);
    Item Item = ItemObject.getFiniteItem();
    when(myClient.streamContacts(DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID, Item.getContactList(), null))
            .thenReturn(responseFlux);
    underTest.tell(new InterimActor.Start(jobId, Item, DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ID));
    expectedPersisted(InterimActor.Started.class);
    underTest.tell(new InterimActor.Pace(2, 2));
    ChildActorProbe.expectMessageClass(ChildActor.Start.class);
    StepVerifier.create(responseFlux)
            .expectSubscription()
            .thenRequest(TWO)
            .expectNext(jsonNode, jsonNode)
            .thenRequest(TWO)
            .expectNext(jsonNode, jsonNode)
            .expectComplete();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you share a bit more info about your issue? Are you using scala or java for akka? Which scala, java and akka version are you using? Could you show what's the full error message you get during the test execution? [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) might help you to improve your question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @GastónSchabas 
1. We are using Java.
2. Akka version: 
def versions = [
        AkkaVersion          : "2.8.3",
        ScalaBinary          : "3",
        AkkaManagementVersion: "1.4.1",
        AkkaHttpVersion      : "10.5.2"
]

3. There is no such error during test execution. The code itself does not get invoked. We are using postgres for durablestate.

Comment: Command is received by the Actor if I configure it to connect to postgres. But in JUnits, testkit should be handling these things.

Comment: Could you edit your post and share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? it's not clear how you write your tests and how they are failing with the details provided.

Comment: Here you have a [test from the persistence teskit repo for durable state](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/main/akka-persistence-testkit/src/test/scala/akka/persistence/testkit/state/scaladsl/PersistenceTestKitDurableStateStoreSpec.scala)

Comment: This test is for scala. I wanted one for Java.

Comment: Updated query with sample code.